# Get a number of delegators of a staking pool in NEAR protocol

Tags: nearprotocol

How can I get the number of delegators per validator?

I see that the block explorer here is pulling a delegators amount: https://explorer.near.org/nodes/validators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a [view function call](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/as/intro#view-and-change-functions) to the [staking pool contract](https://github.com/near/core-contracts/blob/068ec7314c82892f9a6d8b57d8adb90d52a477e1/staking-pool/src/lib.rs#L382)

NEAR Explorer code that does it is here: https://github.com/near/near-explorer/blob/6fb41596299fd8ac073efc413b2d95074ea5d7da/backend/src/index.js#L387-L394